# PHP скрипт работает медленно

Tags: php

Прошу помогите мне решать проблему. Я написала PHP код который делает некоторые действие  со столбцов матрицы. Тут представлено матрица состоящий из 5 столбцов.

Названия столбцов матрицы

```
A  B  C  D  E
```

Суммы столбцов матрицы

```
AB - AC - AD - AE 

ABC-ABCD-ABCDE

ABD-ABDE

ABE

ACD-ACDE

ACE

ADE
___
BC-BD-BE

BCD-BCDE

BCE

BDE
___
CD-CE

CDE
___
DE
```

Столбцы матрицы названы буквами (например первый столбец назван буквой "A", второй столбец назван буквой "B" и т.д.) нужно получить сумму столбцов матрицы как соответственно представлено выше (например "AB" означает "A+B" т.е первый столбец нужно присвоить со вторым столбцом; "ABC" означает "A+B+C" т.е первый столбец + второй столбец+третий столбец; и т.д.). Моя цель сделать те же действия для матрицы состоящий из 197 столбцов и напечатать в результате полученные те столбцы которые содержат число "0" не более чем 1 раз.

Для матрицы состоящий из 5 столбцов код нормально работает можно видеть результат, а для матрицы состоящий из 197 столбцов код работает медленно не получается увидеть результат, потому что в этом случае очень много действии получаются.

```
<?php

$a=array(array(1.2,1.2,2,1.2,0.6,1.8,4.8,2.8,0.8,1.2,2.5,2,1.4,1.3,0.8,0.6, 1.3,1.3,0.6,1.2,1.9,1.5,1.5,2.1,1,6.5,0.9,1.2,0.6,0.4, 0.9, 1.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6,0.8,1,0.6,1.5,0,0.7,0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1, 1, 1.4, 1.5, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 1.5, 1.1,1.1, 0.7, 1.6,3.7,1.8, 1.5, 0.9, 2.2, 2.1, 3.3, 1.9, 2.9, 1.7, 1.5, 4.3, 3, 29.2, 16, 25.2, 18.6, 20, 20, 16.1, 11.8, 10.3, 7.5, 10.3, 5, 23.5, 10.8, 10, 9.9, 10.3, 12.5, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 0.7, 2.5, 3.2, 2.4, 2.9, 1.5, 1.5, 12.7, 17.5, 16.3, 19, 18.9, 18.6, 18, 14.3, 19.5, 18.2, 5.6, 3, 10.6, 11.2, 12.5, 11.2, 13.3, 34.9, 21, 8.98, 21, 20.1, 24, 20.5, 24.4, 6, 1.36, 1.53, 1.5, 0, 4.24, 20.7, 19.4, 1.3, 0, 30.8, 25.8, 10.4, 1.82, 10.76, 0.96, 1.2, 0.62, 3.7, 0.9, 1.9, 2, 1.5, 13.56, 0.7, 0.9, 0.51, 0.61, 1.07, 2.55, 2.12, 1.7, 2, 0.83, 0.6, 0.65, 1.47, 0.73, 0, 2.8, 0.5, 0.4, 1, 0.61, 0, 0.43, 1.24, 3.7, 1, 0.7, 7.91, 4.2,12.72, 14.32, 0.2, 12.8, 20, 0, 0.84, 1, 0.8),
array(0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 5.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.7, 3.7, 0.8, 1, 0.4, 1.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.5, 50.2, 0, 53.6, 57.7, 50, 50, 66.9, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 4.9, 0.2, 2, 3.2, 6.2, 2.2, 2.4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 11.5, 2, 15.3, 13.2, 9.4, 16, 33.3, 22, 18.4, 7.7, 6, 4.12, 3.9, 2.3, 3.9, 2.38, 17.3, 2, 0.7, 1, 4.32, 1.5, 2, 2.2, 0.1, 0.28, 0.17, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 52.9, 48.7, 0, 0, 43.6, 30.8, 3.3, 0.75, 6.7, 1.02, 0.2, 0.02, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 7.02, 0.3, 0.1, 0.27, 0.14, 0.23, 0.95, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.44, 0.6, 0.2, 5.33, 0.51, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.78, 1.1, 0, 0, 75.77, 1.11, 64.37, 66.43, 0.6, 53.2, 5.1, 0, 10.68, 15.3, 0.4),
array(6, 4.5, 13.8, 7.7, 4.6, 4.7, 3.1, 7.9, 5.1, 6, 4.2, 16.3, 8.2, 0, 3, 4.3, 5.7, 4.9, 4.2, 3.4, 6.7, 6.2, 8.8, 12.8, 4.4, 29.9, 9, 6, 9.6, 11.5, 8.1, 21, 14.5, 6.5, 10.3, 10.3, 3, 7.5, 9.5, 9.6, 15.3, 9.8, 5.8, 7.9, 8.2, 15.4, 10.6, 6.6, 7.4, 4.4, 8, 12, 7.5, 3.7, 9.1, 8.3, 8.6, 5.7, 8.9, 10.9, 8, 7.7, 7.3, 9.4, 10.6, 7.6, 12.7, 22.4, 0, 1.1, 1, 3.2, 0.5, 1.2, 1.2, 2, 2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.1, 2, 10.8, 58.5, 12.6, 13.6, 7, 7, 9.9, 59.5, 56.4, 62.3, 60, 8.3, 46, 56, 55.1, 55.8, 14.5, 64.9, 5, 54.5, 5, 5, 2.5, 6.3, 10.5, 6.5, 2, 2.9, 5, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.8, 4.7, 59.6, 54.6, 53.9, 54.6, 73.13, 17.3, 47, 20.13, 59, 46.16, 46.3, 49.5, 41.3, 8.5, 36.26, 23.78, 22.36, 0, 12.9, 10.5, 12.2, 7.4, 0, 7.2, 23.4, 38.6, 15.77, 40.47, 5.84, 4.35, 3.39, 7.6, 2.1, 3.1, 7.03, 2, 58.56, 0, 0, 15.2, 0, 22.22, 14.32, 31.16, 22.8, 13, 16.53, 15.9, 20, 27.09, 5.97, 10.3, 57.4, 14.1, 4.5, 3, 6, 69.2, 12.14, 10.63, 73.6, 9.7, 12.7, 5.22, 49.07, 18.25, 12.27, 0.1, 9.4, 4, 0, 3.06, 0.8, 7.5),
array(5, 5, 23, 30, 15, 45, 100, 50, 60, 5, 70, 20, 10, 5, 10, 23, 250, 200, 25, 25, 29, 20, 10, 6, 8, 10, 10, 5, 23, 20, 60, 0, 4, 45, 5, 71, 40, 38, 10, 10, 15, 10, 7, 0, 15, 6, 15, 20, 20, 15, 150, 2, 60, 15, 30, 25, 23, 200, 70, 15, 40, 25, 200, 17, 15, 10, 10, 650, 30, 8, 34, 12, 11, 6, 6, 6, 8, 12, 2, 7, 6, 6, 2.8, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 100, 55, 43, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8, 5, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20.6, 17.1, 4.5, 0, 1.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 11.7, 12, 10.1, 150, 38, 20, 21.1, 15, 4.2, 53, 36, 27.7, 61.8, 29, 228.3, 20, 19.2, 30, 71.5, 2.7, 59.4, 19.7, 14, 0, 3.5, 1400, 1600, 34, 15.5, 0, 1, 20.3, 13, 45, 10, 1.2, 36, 2, 0.7, 0, 0, 10, 2, 0.9, 0, 60),
array(0.04, 0.04, 0.2, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 0, 0.05, 0.04, 0.1, 0.01, 0.05, 0.06, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 0.08, 0.06, 0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.02, 0.07, 0.05, 0.08, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02, 0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.06, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 0.01, 0.04, 0.01, 3, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.01, 0.03, 0.02, 0.07, 0.02, 0.07, 0.01, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8, 0.4, 0, 0.3, 1, 1, 0.3, 0.44, 0.33, 0.34, 0.38, 0.34, 0, 0.3, 0.47, 0.44, 0.33, 0.22, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.01, 0.03, 0.08, 0.03, 0.1, 0.19, 0.03, 0.07, 0, 0.08, 0, 0.1, 0.06, 0.05, 0.52, 0.05, 0.07, 0.06, 0.02, 0.46, 0.39, 0.46, 0.39, 0.39, 0.94, 0.5, 0.245, 0, 0.08, 0.5, 0.81, 0, 0.06, 0.087, 0.112, 0.095, 0, 0.143, 1.27, 0, 0, 0.11, 0, 0.11, 0.025, 0.198, 0.044, 0.05, 0.029, 0.05, 0.02, 0.1, 0.2, 0.03, 0.116, 0.07, 0.08, 0.058, 0.027, 0.11, 0.067, 0.01, 0.08, 0, 0.011, 0.05, 0.013, 0.374, 0.014, 0, 0.428, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.21, 0, 0.04, 1.195, 0.16, 0.867, 0.617, 0, 0.09, 0.07, 0.8, 0.003, 0.021, 0.03),
array(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.03, 0.04, 0.2, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.07, 0.02, 0.07, 0.04, 0.04, 0.08, 0.09, 0.04, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.02, 0.03, 0.08, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.06, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.04, 0.05, 3, 0.05, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.15, 0.13, 0.08, 0.14, 0.19, 0, 0.14, 0.12, 0.2, 0.13, 0.06, 0.03, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.03, 0.44, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.15, 0.2, 0.14, 0.22, 0.15, 0.3, 0.1, 0.16, 0.07, 0.13, 0.07, 0.27, 0.22, 0.18, 0.071, 0, 0, 0.21, 0.15, 0, 0.1, 0.048, 0.032, 0.025, 0, 0.059, 0.18, 0.36, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.18, 0.034, 0.182, 0.035, 0.06, 0.022, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.06, 0.08, 0.2, 0.02, 0.1, 0.057, 0.032, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02, 0.1, 0.13, 0.065, 0.015, 0.022, 0.2, 0.06, 0, 0.152, 0, 0.06, 0, 0.026, 0.05, 0, 0.032, 0.36, 0, 0.02, 0.162, 0.18, 0.131, 0.035, 0, 0.3, 1, 0, 0, 0.007, 0.05),
array(0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.04, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.06, 0, 0.04, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.05, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.06, 0.4, 0.5, 0.04, 0.03, 0.2, 0.06, 0.07, 0.06, 0.08, 0, 0.08, 0.09, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.05, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.06, 0.08, 0.03, 0.07, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.06, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.47, 0.54, 0.48, 0.17, 0, 0.34, 0.26, 0.41, 0.47, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.14, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.43, 0, 0.43, 0.482, 0.85, 0.9, 0.106, 0, 0, 0, 0.27, 0, 0, 0.088, 0.293, 0.283, 0, 0.266, 1.345, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.291, 0.16, 0.23, 0.056, 0.043, 0.04, 0.2, 0.08, 0, 0.215, 0.2, 0.591, 0, 0, 0.134, 0.019, 0.1, 0.11, 0, 0.221, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.316, 0.06, 0, 0.066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0.275, 0.41, 0.192, 0.101, 0, 0, 0, 8.6, 0.009, 0.031,0.06),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 6.5, 5.3, 3.2, 3, 4.0836, 6.2, 4, 3.5, 6.5, 4.7, 0.749, 2.59, 0.749, 0.749, 0.2, 1.4, 0.9, 0.8984, 1.2, 0.6, 0.729, 3.6, 2.905, 5.205, 3.154, 5.4374, 8.2, 7.988, 5.8, 13.3, 12.5, 1.2296, 0.598, 5.1425, 5.7, 0, 5.7, 0, 9.7, 6.4, 0.811, 0, 3.3366, 5.5, 6.5, 4.166, 1.596, 0.854, 0.552, 0.6, 0, 1.693, 15.7, 11.1, 1, 0, 15.9, 4.2828, 1.143, 0.75, 1.102, 1.85, 0.4, 0.32, 1.6, 0.5, 1.4, 0, 0.9, 0.923, 0, 0, 0.584, 0.338, 0.9, 0, 1.8, 0.5, 0, 0.603, 0.43, 1.35, 1.074, 0.46, 0, 1.938, 0, 0, 0, 0.302, 0, 0, 0.289, 0, 0.166, 0.9162, 2.473, 0.8, 0.907, 0.295, 0, 4.0248, 11.32, 0, 0.037, 0.4),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.52, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2.6, 2, 2, 0, 0.6, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.451, 0, 0.135, 0, 0, 0.103, 0.018, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.143, 0, 0.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.228, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.746, 0.184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.015,  0.023, 0.3), 
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
array(0, 0.02, 0.3, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 9, 0.06, 0, 2, 1, 1.2, 0, 0.02, 0.1, 0.01, 0.02, 1.5, 0, 1.6, 0.02, 0.4, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.06, 0.5, 0.1, 1.2, 0.03, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 10, 9, 1.2, 0.04, 0.2, 0.1, 1.4, 0.2, 1.5, 0.02, 2.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.01, 2, 0, 0, 53, 67, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 100, 166.66, 100, 10, 750, 0, 4200, 750, 417, 100,  260, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0, 2, 0, 2, 9, 12, 0, 4, 0, 15, 5, 2, 0, 0.05, 1, 7, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 410, 16, 950, 750, 83, 375, 292, 0, 0, 0, 38, 55, 0, 0, 21, 2, 64, 0, 0, 2, 44, 2, 0, 2, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 3.3333, 0, 10, 131, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 20, 0, 5),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.32, 0.4, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.06, 4.5, 0, 0, 4.5, 2.5, 0, 0.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.03, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.083, 0.035, 0, 0.011, 0.03, 0, 13.9, 0, 0, 0, 310, 0, 0, 0.063, 0, 0, 5.7, 4.5, 0.5, 225, 1.75, 0.001, 30, 360, 0,445, 0.276, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.743, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0.025, 0, 0.018, 0, 305, 0, 0.035, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.6, 0.237, 0.231, 0.03),
 array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.1, 1.6, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 18, 2, 1.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 1.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 30.9, 6, 6, 25.5, 3, 1.7, 0.8, 1.3, 0.2, 0, 0.8, 1.4, 2.8, 1.7, 1.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1.7, 0.1, 0, 2.5, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0, 2.7, 0.6, 0, 0.6, 0.08, 1.9, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.19, 0.35, 2.38, 0, 0, 31.2, 2.3, 0, 0, 7.4, 0, 1.04, 0.26, 0, 0.38, 0.1, 0, 1.8, 0.5, 2, 0, 0.7, 1.19, 0, 0, 1.12, 0.73, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.07, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.18, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.54, 0, 0, 5.73, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1.65, 3.81, 0.5),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 260, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 482.9, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 2.3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 163.7, 0.1, 0, 10.1, 0.7, 0, 1640, 0, 0, 0, 173.6, 0, 0, 0, 4.2, 2.6, 0.5, 2.6, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.8, 0, 1.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.4, 1.4, 0),
array(15, 15, 34, 40, 15, 48, 34, 46, 53, 15, 26, 10, 31, 27, 23, 13, 8, 0, 14, 39, 35, 49, 37, 20, 25, 180, 28, 15, 23, 16, 34, 8, 10, 23, 19, 38, 40, 35, 20, 20, 127, 16, 14, 0, 40, 30, 37, 16, 16, 30, 19, 35, 40, 14, 22, 40, 32, 42, 42, 0, 36, 36, 36, 32, 33, 16, 24, 28, 13, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 3, 6, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 85, 124, 47, 273, 250, 250, 170, 54, 93, 40, 34, 26, 192, 70, 117, 59, 93, 58, 40, 115, 40, 40, 44, 223, 119, 0, 106, 47, 40, 55, 0, 3, 11, 8, 9, 10, 7, 12, 16, 178, 124, 99, 51, 57, 51, 180, 0, 150, 16, 0, 193, 83, 115, 141, 0, 16, 17, 43, 0, 6, 367, 1474, 0, 0, 454, 254, 443, 16, 383, 7, 20, 26, 245, 72, 21, 81, 77, 159, 27, 63, 10, 24, 17, 18, 39, 30, 12, 5, 15, 22, 6, 56, 0, 74, 0, 10, 0, 3.4, 65, 16, 17, 79, 58, 24, 85, 18, 61, 160, 5, 28, 495, 2191, 88, 52, 40),
array(34, 34, 49, 41, 12, 31, 78, 50, 32, 34, 51, 58, 58, 55, 42, 12, 16, 26, 44, 26, 34, 43, 78, 25, 100, 26, 34, 24, 11, 23, 28, 0, 18, 16, 31, 22, 17, 34, 20, 42, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0, 30, 8, 12, 32, 35, 14, 23, 11, 28, 37, 24, 9, 17, 0, 23, 33, 25, 28, 13, 0, 8, 89, 0, 44, 0, 45, 171, 70, 41, 0, 40, 0, 115, 0, 390, 564, 206, 473, 400, 299, 370, 353, 328, 301, 122, 358, 334, 361, 366, 353, 325, 50, 192, 50, 50, 25, 93, 130, 0, 83, 90, 50, 192, 0, 178, 197, 187, 188, 200, 164, 200, 0, 158, 92, 298, 320, 400, 320, 429, 0, 480, 122, 0, 444, 390, 329, 630, 44, 27, 55, 84, 0, 98, 530, 720, 25, 0, 840, 650, 158, 34, 178, 39, 32, 13, 95, 77, 62, 63, 34, 557, 26, 23, 11, 5, 30, 40, 28, 21, 68, 31, 11, 9, 39, 24, 0, 113, 0, 9, 12, 11.1, 56, 27, 0, 0, 34, 0, 188, 96, 336, 725, 7, 500, 824, 0.5, 3, 4, 0),
array(9, 9, 28, 14, 9, 16, 40, 30, 16, 0, 17, 23, 14, 38, 14, 26, 11, 7, 20, 13, 22, 17, 22, 12, 14, 30, 8, 9, 14, 11, 13, 42, 2, 10, 12, 24, 12, 11, 16, 9, 56, 9, 224, 0, 7, 17, 26, 7, 13, 29, 21, 17, 18, 8, 9, 22, 15, 30, 33, 0, 9, 17, 31, 17, 24, 6, 51, 8, 15, 0, 7, 0, 0, 15, 8, 0, 11, 0, 15, 0, 202, 198, 270, 234, 0, 200, 172, 108, 150, 116, 104, 38, 174, 258, 135, 120, 150, 111, 30, 92, 30, 30, 17, 70, 36, 0, 82, 85, 30, 12, 0, 18, 25, 25, 22, 20, 24, 19, 18, 11, 14, 127, 130, 104, 130, 184, 0, 108, 55, 0, 126, 80, 107, 99, 0, 21, 21, 33, 0, 25, 317, 540, 10, 0, 311, 238, 171, 43, 229, 20, 14, 11, 85, 50, 20, 57, 40, 248, 0, 0, 9, 10, 25, 22, 30, 18, 29, 10, 16, 7, 30, 85, 0, 92, 0, 12, 10, 0, 69, 13, 9, 37, 26, 51, 130, 84, 173, 376, 0, 80, 440, 911, 4, 11, 18),
array(238, 238, 397, 238, 238, 300, 375, 370, 300, 238, 210, 568, 175, 200, 141, 203, 163, 0, 290, 357, 238, 288, 200, 204, 260, 305, 238, 144, 321, 197, 348, 150, 184, 155, 295, 163, 155, 363, 214, 200, 278, 64, 0, 73, 225, 256, 51, 118, 208, 70, 190, 161, 119, 260, 224, 238, 103, 230, 0, 270, 275, 350, 239, 233, 51, 350, 23, 468, 0, 400, 443, 404, 310, 0, 269, 0, 530, 0, 732, 664, 0, 748, 600, 600, 717, 337, 453, 314, 340, 285, 1000, 325, 421, 424, 453, 351, 0, 2043, 260, 260, 325, 335, 579, 0, 774, 500, 260, 140, 0, 270, 250, 263, 326, 325, 285, 210, 194, 198, 146, 246, 328, 350, 0, 427, 0, 1100, 441, 0, 968, 672, 873, 633, 0, 271, 816, 591, 0, 454, 647, 497, 139, 0, 979, 608, 1329, 415, 1119, 268, 139, 150, 800, 430, 196, 303, 220, 508, 235, 236, 156, 257, 490, 417, 344, 382, 348, 171, 47, 42, 436, 220, 0, 628, 0, 97, 133, 0, 370, 266, 155, 531, 363, 350, 368, 447, 436, 659, 90, 747, 2480, 1110, 8, 42, 161),
array(20, 6, 0, 10, 2, 13, 7, 10, 4, 0, 10, 5, 4, 21, 0, 14, 19, 2, 40, 10, 13, 17, 46, 3, 4, 17, 3, 20, 0, 24, 13, 31, 2, 13, 14, 4, 11, 12, 30, 18, 15, 26, 16, 0, 7, 26, 20, 6, 32, 21, 35, 18, 18, 12, 23, 10, 22, 4, 0.8, 0, 2, 21, 32, 0, 13, 6, 16, 5, 6, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 26, 3, 0, 22, 0, 25, 3, 8, 32, 30, 27, 2, 40, 4, 37, 4, 32, 23, 70, 141, 70, 0, 2, 43, 100, 0, 24, 15, 70, 134, 0, 80, 80, 108, 65, 65, 58, 90, 70, 26, 50, 28, 28, 8, 328, 12, 0, 40, 6, 0, 72, 55, 33, 49, 0, 14, 9, 11, 0, 26, 160, 75, 7, 0, 139, 37, 20, 13, 18, 1, 3, 2, 34, 200, 2, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 2, 2,10, 4, 28, 1, 1, 10.9, 2, 5, 0, 28, 0, 3, 2, 0, 32, 1, 3, 9, 32, 16, 5, 3, 1, 3, 0, 5, 82, 0, 872, 1556, 18),
array(47, 47, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 47, 0, 47, 0, 58, 25, 63, 25, 0, 19, 0, 57, 44, 0, 0, 43, 47, 19, 30, 1, 47, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 47, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 1, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 25, 0, 39, 30, 30, 22, 29, 125, 133, 54, 34.25, 0, 94, 119, 46, 125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 156, 165, 60, 0, 0, 59, 60, 60, 90, 77, 76, 0, 47, 36, 0, 36, 0, 0, 58, 0, 0, 50, 75, 137, 116, 0, 23.7, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16),  
array(0.4, 0.4, 1, 1.5, 0, 0.6, 1.3, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 1.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 0.9, 1.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.5, 0.7, 0.4, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 1, 0.5, 2.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.1, 0.6, 0.5, 2.5, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1, 0.8, 3.2, 1.2, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.5, 0.4, 2, 0, 0.5, 0, 1.3, 1.9, 1.8, 0.7, 0, 11.5, 0.5, 0, 0.7, 1.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3, 2.7, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.3, 0, 6, 2.3, 0, 4.2, 60, 60, 3, 5.4, 7.4, 2.1, 3.7, 0.7, 6, 8.3, 5.5, 5.4, 7.4, 3, 0.5, 3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 1.6, 2, 0, 13.51, 2, 0.5, 2.5, 0.7, 2, 2.2, 1.3, 2.7, 3, 1.7, 1.4, 1.6, 0.09, 0.1, 4.41, 3.5, 5.7, 3.5, 7.63, 0, 5.9, 2.35, 0, 2.6, 11.8, 6.8, 8.34, 1.1, 0.27, 0.54, 0.55, 0, 2.22, 6.1, 16, 750, 0, 6.3, 25, 9.71, 0.6, 13.97, 0.62, 0.36, 0.2, 1.9, 1.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 7.61, 0.5, 0.4, 0.13, 0.1, 0.54, 0.26, 1, 0.71, 1.16, 0.31, 0.4, 0.35, 0.43, 0.3, 0, 2.8, 0, 0, 0, 1.01, 1.5, 0.28, 0.08, 1.8, 4.1, 0, 3.69, 1.41, 2.12, 2.43, 2, 4.1, 0.2, 36, 3.3, 0.49, 1.2,),
 array(290, 290, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 290, 0, 290, 0, 360, 850, 400, 215, 0, 440, 0, 200, 200, 0, 0, 425, 290, 240, 1025, 82, 290, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 190, 290, 125, 0, 100, 100, 0, 150, 0, 0, 0, 91, 300, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 90, 200, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1100, 330, 0, 260, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 280, 0, 0, 2570, 0, 2120, 2800, 2440, 2.79, 2.71, 1.8, 1.73, 0.795, 0, 2.77, 3.61, 2.04, 2.71, 3.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.91, 0, 0, 0.53, 0, 0, 1.11, 0.7, 3, 0, 0, 3.24, 3, 3, 2.45, 2.055, 0.22, 0, 2.17, 2.97, 0, 2.92, 3.63, 2.01, 3.21, 1.58, 0, 2.86, 2.42, 3.18, 3.11, 0, 0.34, 0.24, 0.23, 0, 0.63, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.19, 0.34, 7.47, 0.22, 0.07, 0.7, 1.07, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.27, 2.87, 0, 0, 0.04, 0.07, 0.12, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.07, 0.1, 80, 0.28, 0.12, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0.04, 0.19, 0, 0, 1.3, 0.87, 4.31, 4.06, 0, 4.5, 0, 4, 0.22, 40, 0.097),
array(2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 5, 3, 5, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 1, 9, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 2, 0, 2, 0, 90, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 3.1, 0, 2, 10, 10, 0.2, 8, 8.9, 2.3, 5.2, 1.275, 0, 5.1, 7.5, 9.3, 8.9, 0, 9, 0, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 20, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7.2, 7, 7, 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 6.1, 0, 6.1, 0, 8.2, 12.1, 0, 0, 3.4, 3.5, 5.1, 3.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
array(135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 140, 85, 80, 100, 0, 110, 150, 0, 0, 140, 135, 180, 130, 170, 135, 0, 0, 67, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 240, 0, 50, 87, 0, 110, 0, 0, 0, 80, 100, 0, 47, 0, 90, 0, 125, 0, 130, 170, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37000, 0, 0, 290, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 527, 0, 140, 500, 1125, 470, 470, 560, 290, 187.5, 0, 660, 600, 460, 470, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 146, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 83, 109, 180, 0, 506, 182, 180, 85, 76, 13, 0, 390, 560, 0, 560, 0.81, 500, 580, 205, 0, 660, 660, 750, 590, 0, 100, 178, 172, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.33, 226, 383, 79, 0.035, 0.026, 149, 0, 0, 0.094, 120, 525, 0, 0, 110, 16, 84, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.09, 148, 80, 66, 0.207, 80, 0, 86, 0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 55, 0.27, 0, 0, 756, 363, 0.738, 1743, 0, 2275, 0, 0, 251, 120, 125),
array(210, 210, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 210, 0, 210, 0, 170, 230, 200, 180, 0, 160, 0, 140, 150, 0, 0, 660, 210, 40, 810, 220, 210, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 65, 210, 40, 0, 140, 110, 0, 47, 0, 0, 650, 90, 80, 0, 35, 0, 90, 0, 200, 0, 450, 210, 0, 0, 2000, 0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19000, 230, 0, 410, 0, 0, 740, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1900, 0, 1920, 3800, 3800, 4200, 3.76, 1.48, 3.63, 1.09, 0.4375, 0, 1.76, 5.25, 2.77, 1.48, 3.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.264, 0, 0, 0.897, 0, 0, 0.029, 0.15, 0.035, 0, 0.02, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.014, 0.019, 0.011, 0, 2.459, 1.85, 9.24, 2.8, 1.34, 0.881, 0, 2.14, 1.19, 1.75, 1.72, 0, 0.397, 0.383, 0, 0.174, 1.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.75, 0.229, 28, 0.153, 0.092, 0.066, 0.16, 0, 0, 0.99, 0.3, 3.333, 0, 0, 0.027, 0.011, 0.06, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 0.055, 65, 343, 0.325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.148, 0.085, 0.31, 0, 0, 4.131, 1.601, 4.61, 1.223, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.2),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 19, 0, 29, 22.1, 20, 30, 3.275, 0, 0, 23.8, 25.8, 22.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 31.7, 12.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.4, 0, 24.9, 3.6, 0, 28.5, 19.6, 13.1, 27.2, 0, 0.7, 0, 0.7, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.9, 0.7, 0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.6, 18.7, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 1.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.6, 0, 8.1, 1917, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.9, 0),
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 2, 3, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 11, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.6, 2.8, 8, 2.25, 0, 6, 12.8, 7.2, 10.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 55, 10, 0, 0, 8.2, 10, 11, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7.8, 0, 7.8, 0, 16, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10.8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2),
array(10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 20, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 12, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4330, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 25, 0, 23.6, 13.8, 26.7, 28.4, 21, 0, 38.5, 39, 18, 13.8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 12, 0, 0, 11,6, 12, 12, 29, 0, 8, 0, 0, 19.5, 0, 19.5, 0, 99, 39.4, 0, 0, 60.2, 77.5, 84.2, 67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10),                
array(14, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 30, 31, 55, 17.1, 0, 7, 0, 20, 30, 0, 0, 20, 14, 86, 0, 11, 14, 0, 0,  17, 0, 0, 0, 10, 14, 10, 0, 22, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 12, 13, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 685, 0, 91, 0, 0, 17, 0, 106, 80, 64, 7.5, 0, 33, 117, 67, 106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 430, 63, 0, 0, 63, 63, 63, 0, 130, 0, 0, 0, 79, 0, 79, 0, 120, 44, 0, 0, 0, 25, 30, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10000, 0, 0, 0, 18));

$b=array();
$b1=array();
$c=array();
$c1=array();
$d=array();
$e=array();

Matrix($a,$b,$b1,$c,$c1,$d,$e);

function Matrix($a,$b,$b1,$c,$c1,$d,$e)
{
$M=32;
$N=197;
$x1=0;
$x2=0;
$k=0;
for($k=0;$k<$N-1;$k++)
{
    echo "<b>All variants for column $k</b><br>";
    for($j=0;$j<$N-$k-1;$j++)
    {
        $l=0;   
        for($i=0;$i<$M;$i++)
        {   
            $b[$i][$j]=$a[$i][$k]+$a[$i][$j+$k+1];
            if($b[$i][$j]==0)
                $l++;
        }
        if ($l<2)
        {
            echo '<i>columns</i> '.$k;
            echo ' + ';
            echo $j+$k+'1'.'<br>';
            for($i=0;$i<$M;$i++)
            {
                echo $b[$i][$j]."<br>";
                $d[$i][$x1]=$b[$i][$j];
            }
            $x1++;
        }   
    }
    for($f=0;$f<$N-1;$f++)
    {
        $v=$f+2;
        if($v<$N)
        {
            for($h=$f+2;$h<$N-$k;$h++)
            {
                $x=$f+1;
                $y=$k+$x;
                $z="$k + $y";
                $u=$h;
                for($g=0;$g<$N-$h-$k;$g++)
                {
                    if($u<$N)
                    {
                        $s=$u+$k;
                        $z=$z." + $s";
                        $l=0;
                        for($i=0;$i<$M;$i++)
                        {
                            if($g == 0)
                            {
                                $c[$i][$g] = $b[$i][$g+$f]+$a[$i][$g+$h+$k];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $c[$i][$g] = $c[$i][$g-1]+$a[$i][$g+$h+$k];
                            }
                            if($c[$i][$g]==0)
                                $l++;
                        }
                        if ($l<2)
                        {
                            echo '<i>columns</i> ';
                            echo $z;
                            echo '<br>'.'<br>';
                            for($i=0;$i<$M;$i++)
                            {
                                echo $c[$i][$g]."<br>";
                                $e[$i][$x2] = $c[$i][$g];
                            }
                            $x2++;
                        }   
                    }
                    $u++;   
                }   
            }
        }
        $v++;
    }
}   
echo '<b><i>Total matrix</i> B</b>'.'<br>';
Tpel($d,$M,$x1);
echo '<b><i>Total matrix</i> C</b>'.'<br>';
Tpel($e,$M,$x2);
}
function Tpel($a,$M,$N)
{
?>
<table>
<?
for($i=0;$i<$M;$i++)
{
?>
    <tr>
    <?
    for($j=0;$j<$N;$j++)
    {
    ?>
        <td>
        <?
            echo $a[$i][$j].'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        ?>
        </td>
    <?
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
<?  
}
?>
</table>
<?
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: У вас в примере нет отрицательных чисел, они возможны?

Comment: Без комментариев в коде не разобраться. К тому же именование переменных просто удручает

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал хранить промежуточные результаты вычислений и их активно использовать в последующих вычислениях. Ну алгоритм приблизительно следующий:

- Сначала вычислить все сложения 2 столбцов
- Сложения 3-х столбцов разбить на 2 + 1
- Сложение 4-х столбцов разбить на 2 + 2 или 3 + 1
- Повторять до победного

Если не нужен сильный прирост производительности, то можно изначально подсчитать сумму столбцов и уже оперировать ими.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте через БД, и вычисления делать сразу в запросе. Тогда возможно будет плюс в производительности.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly

Comment: Существенный плюс в производительности будет при смене алгоритма, а не при смене инструмента